# orthogonal subspaces in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Here is the question:

Let W be a subspace of $R^n$ with an orthogonal basis {$w_1$,...,$w_p$}, and let {$v_1$,...,$v_q$} be and orthogonal basis for W$\perp$. Assume that both p >= 1 and q>=1.

(1) For the case when n=2, describe geometrically W and W$\perp$. In particular, what are the possible dimensions of these two subspaces?

(2) For the case when n=3.....

My confusion is because I was under the impression that an orthogonal basis must consist of at least two vectors, because one vector cannot be orthogonal alone. But, if W is a two dimension subspace, then how can W$\perp$ be in $R^2$? If W is 2 dimensions, then the only orthogonal subspace would be a line in $R^3$. It seems to me that if both W and W$\perp$ are an orthogonal basis for a subspace, they must each span 2 vectors and together reside in a higher dimension than $R^2$. I also know that the union set of these two subspaces must span $R^2$ by definition, which tells me that there must be a total of two orthogonal vectors. Can someone give me a hint on what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Your impression is incorrect: a set consisting of a single vector is considered to be orthogonal since it is true that any vector in this set is orthogonal to anything else in it, simply because there is no other vector in the set on which to test this condition.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder in case you don’t know how the site works: after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "upvote" and/or "accept" the answer by clicking the up arrow and the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question and will encourage others to answer your other questions. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^2=W\oplus W^\perp$ (read about [direct sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) and [orthogonal complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) ) so $\dim(\mathbb{R}^2)=\dim(W)+\dim(W^\perp)$. Since $\dim(\mathbb R^2)=2$, consider the two cases for $\dim(W)$ and $\dim(W^\perp)$:

- $\dim(W)=0$ and $\dim(W^\perp)=2$
- $\dim(W)=1$ and $\dim(W^\perp)=1$
- $\dim(W)=2$ and $\dim(W^\perp)=0$

But you were told $p\geq 1$ and $q\ge1$ so the first and third are ruled out. Hence, $\dim(W)=\dim(W^\perp)=1$.

Geometrically, these are two lines in $\mathbb R^2$. For example, envision $\mathbb R^2$ as $W\oplus W^\perp$ where $W:=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb R\}$ and $W^\perp:=\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb R\}$. These are just the two lines in $\mathbb R^2$ formed by the $x$ axis and $y$ axis in standard coordinates.

> (2) For the case when n=3.....

I'm not sure what your question is. Is it to find the dimensions of $W$ and $W^\perp$? If so, case it out just as above, but this time knowing the dimensions sum to $3$. Then either

- $\dim(W)=3$ and $\dim(W^\perp)=0$
- $\dim(W)=2$ and $\dim(W^\perp)=1$ (Think: $xy$ plane and $z$ axis.)
- $\dim(W)=1$ and $\dim(W^\perp)=2$ (Think: $x$ axis and $yz$ plane.)
- $\dim(W)=0$ and $\dim(W^\perp)=3$.

Again the $p,q\geq 1$ condition rules out the first and last of these. The middle two cases are (geometrically) a line and a plane in $\mathbb R^3$.

> My confusion is because I was under the impression that an orthogonal
>   basis must consist of at least two vectors, because one vector cannot
>   be orthogonal alone.

What if the space is 1 or 0 dimensional? Then no basis for that space can have two vectors in it.

Answer (score 0):

If W is a space of two dimensions then it is not a subspace of R^2 it is the whole space.

The space perpendicular to W is null.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).